# Can I get every month of the year even if there is not data for that month in DB

Tags: mysql

I want to get a statistic for every month of the years i have in DB

```
SELECT      monthname(created_at) AS month, YEAR(created_at) AS year, count(*) AS number
FROM        tableName
WHERE       type_of_user = "someType"
GROUP BY    year, month(created_at)
ORDER BY    created_at DESC
```

Now it gives me only month that I have, but I need to get statistics  for every month, even if I don't have any stored data for that month

Comment: You can do a join on a calendar-table, that holds all the months.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `calendar` table. This will need one entry per month, for every year that you intend to use.

Then select from the calendar table, and join in the values that you get from your current query. Use `COALESCE()` to put a zero-value where the entry is NULL (e.g. when there are no records in the `tableName` for that month and year).

```sql
SELECT MONTHNAME(date) as month, 
       YEAR(date) as year,
       COALESCE(number, 0) as number
FROM calendar AS C
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT created_at, COUNT(*) as number
  FROM tableName AS T
  WHERE T.type_of_user = 'someType'
  GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)
) AS T 
ON MONTH(T.created_at) = MONTH(C.date) AND YEAR(T.created_at) = YEAR(C.date)
GROUP BY month, YEAR(created_at)
ORDER BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date)
```

- SQL fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0a4dc/

Comment: this looks good, but I can't really create a table for all moths for JOIN is there a possibility to create calendar table for this particular query?

Comment: Just create the calendar table, and populate it 10+ years ahead of time - and leave it be. You have one table with all the dates, not one table for each year/month.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month(created_at) as month
FROM tableName
RIGHT JOIN (select row_number() over (order by 1) as i 
       from someTableWithMoreThan12Records limit 12) x
    ON x.i=month(created_at)
ORDER BY I;
```

JOINing with a table that has all the records will give you every month.